# How to use fragments to emulate back button when I show/hide elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use jQuery to show/hide elements that correspond to a multi-step solution. Now I've been asked to make the back button functional.

I understand that using fragments can aid here but I'm not sure how. If I set the hash when I show/hide my elements (as I move from step to step) via:

```
if($(button).hasClass('step-one')) {
        $('.step-two').show();
        window.location.hash = "#step2";
    }
```

Now I've got my hash set correctly but when I click the back button it only removes the hash. It does a...

```
window.history.back;
```

How do I get it to return to the previous step without completely re-architecting what I've done? Or without using a 3rd party plugin like BBQ or Ben Alman's Hashchange plugin?

Thanks for any helpful tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try to work with **onhashchange**..

Try handle your events (show and hide) using this:

```
$(window).on('hashchange',function(){

    var hash = window.location.hash;
    switch(hash){
        case '#step1':
            console.log('Make something superb!');
            break;
        case '#step2':
            console.log('Make something superb!');
            break;
        case '#step3':
            console.log('Make something superb!');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

})
```

I dont know if this is gonna work... I didnt test it... But i think you can start with this....
I also suggest you to hanfle the hashs with anchors:

```
<a href='#step1'></a>
```

Comment: It's definitely a very good start, thank you very much. After implementing this the only problem is that if the hash is #step1 and I click back, the hash is removed but the content stays the same.

Comment: Wasn't thinking, apologies. Thanks for your answer.